# Serializing fields of an IEnumerable class to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, ienumerable

I am trying to serialize the following classes.

```
[XmlRoot("SerializableThing")]
public class SerializableThing : IEnumerable<SubThing>
{
    public List<SubThing> SubThings = new List<SubThing>();

    [XmlElement]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public void Add(SubThing sub)
    {
        SubThings.Add(sub);
    }

    public IEnumerator<SubThing> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return SubThings.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class SubThing
{
    public string SubId;
}
```

Serialization code (pretty vanilla):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerializableThing main = new SerializableThing();
    SubThing sub = new SubThing();

    main.Id = "hiiiii";
    sub.SubId = "hello";

    main.Add(sub);

    SaveXML(main, new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableThing)), "hi.xml");
}

static void SaveXML(object data, XmlSerializer serializer, string xmlPath)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Create(xmlPath))
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream)) {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Now, the output is this. Notice that it *is* the enumerable (`List<SubThing>`) and not an instance of `SerializableThing`.

```
<SerializableThing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SubThing>
    <SubId>hello</SubId>
  </SubThing>
</SerializableThing>
```

The goal is to get `Id` to be serialized. Can I trick the serializer into treating `SerializableThing` as an essentially normal class with a list as a property?

Comment: My guess is that `Id` simply isn't getting serialized because it is a property instead of a public field. Have you tried removing the getter and setter from `Id`?

Comment: I've tried it as a field yes.

Comment: I did some googling around and it seems to be a known problem (with no easy solution). There seems to be a similar limitation when implementing ICollection (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization#serializing-a-class-that-implements-the-icollection-interface)). It might be wise to explore other avenues in this case: avoid implementing `IEnumerable`, use different type of serialization if possible, etc.

Comment: You just need to use : public List<SubThing> SubThings { get;set;}  Then add [XmlElement] above the object.